# Dataflow working: Combine functions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have multiple custom combine functions which I call as such:

e.g. I have 'data' calculated previously in the pipeline.

```
cd1 = data | customCombFn1()
cd2 = data | customCombFn2()
cd3 = data | customCombFn3()
```

How does the pipeline work in the above case ? Is the 'data' evaluated again and again ? Or are `cd1`, `cd2`, and `cd3` evaluated as a by-product of the pipeline ?

Answer (score 3):

Your `data` object is a PCollection. Applying a combine transformation on a PCollection creates another PCollection, most often containing much fewer elements.

There would be no 're-evaluation', as you call it. PCollection is typically produced on multiple workers and immediately consumed by transformations that need it. If that is not possible in a given case, PCollection will typically be stored for processing at a later point.

Generally speaking, Cloud Dataflow service automatically applies optimizations to users' pipeline. In most cases, including this one, it allows users to focus on their business logic instead of the underlying execution considerations.

Comment: so there are no inherent optimizations to club customCombFn1, customCombFn2 and customCombFn3 as a dict aggregator right ? Is there any paper or blog which describes the same ? I assumed that above code was akin to traversing through the complete data three times as I have three combine operations.

Comment: It is more complicated than that. Dataflow Service applies several types of optimizations, depending on the pipeline structure. Sometimes part of the Combine transformation are "lifted" into preceding parts of the pipeline, or re-ordered, or optimized in some other way. In general, we attempt to execute combine transformations as soon as possible, since that reduces the amount of data and normally speeds up the pipeline.